# Remove default buttons from Button Panel in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to keep the button panel but I do not want the 'Today' or 'Done' buttons

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonText: "Date",
            showButtonPanel: true
        });
});
```

html:

```
<div>
    <label for="start">Start</label>
    <input id="start" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="end">End</label>
    <input id="end" type="text" class="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post some code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

apparently the solution I provided is kinda outdated. Please see the answer below for a working fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806307/959041

---

you should add the option

```
showButtonPanel: false
```

so you have

```
$("#test").datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: false
});
```

**UPDATE**

to remove the buttons but be able to add other buttons you can use the `beforeShow` event. So you have something like

```
$("#test").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane")
            .html('')
            .append("<button>new button</button>");
    }
});
```

see http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#buttonbar for the documentation

Comment: I still want the area to be able to add my own button(s) too. I just dont want the default buttons

Comment: I made the changes and it doesnt seem to work
http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/zEper/7/

Answer (score 1):

I just took previous answer and found how to make it work, but this looks ugly.

Basically what I added is setTimeout as it seems that content of buttons pane is rendered after beforeShow event:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Date',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function (){
        setTimeout(function() {
         $(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane")
            .html('')
            .append("<button>new button</button>");
        }, 1)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zEper/278/